# Cancel different onGoing notifications

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have different Ongoing notifications. When an addAction() button is pressed a BroadcastReceiver is called and my notification is cleaned. The problem is the addAction() always pass the id of the last notification added, not the one that you pressed:

[image: This is what happens]

Here is the method adding the notification:

```
    public void pushNotification(View v){
      String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
      editText.setText("");
      int millis = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationReceiver.class);
      notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      notificationIntent.putExtra("id", millis);
      PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

      NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
      notification.setContentTitle("");
      notification.setContentText(text);
      notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
      notification.setOngoing(true);
      notification.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Dismiss", pIntent);

      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      notificationManager.notify(millis, notification.build());
    }
```

Receiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
      NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      manager.cancel(intent.getIntExtra("id", 0));
  }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="PACKAGE_NAME">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just add `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` to your pending intent and now all the `extras` will be different.